# Could not get pipeline: errorSave (domain: )

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8.1

Using Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 151207) and installed Web Forms For Marketers 8.1 rev. 151217 Update-1.
Created a sample form with send email message save action and on submit it throws an error  - Could not get pipeline: errorSave (domain: ),
however when i try to preview it on CM and submit the form it shows a success message and also email is received successfully.

Here is the some log info from CD:

```
INFO  Event started: media:request
INFO  Executed: Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler.OnMediaRequest(). Elapsed: 0.00928889006843048
INFO  Event ended: media:request. Elapsed: 0.0689333420867736
INFO  Event started: sessionEnd:starting
INFO  Event ended: sessionEnd:starting. Elapsed: 0.0106857156426306
INFO  Event started: sessionEnd:postSessionEnd:starting
INFO  Event ended: sessionEnd:postSessionEnd:starting. Elapsed: 0.00551746101809029
INFO  Event started: sessionEnd:ended
INFO  Event ended: sessionEnd:ended. Elapsed: 0.00453968311615024
WARN  [WFFM] Tracker.Current  is not initialized
WARN  [WFFM] Tracker.Current.CurrentPage  is not initialized
INFO  Event started: publish:statusUpdated
INFO  Executed: Sitecore.Publishing.RemotePublishingEventHandler.OnStatusUpdated(). Elapsed: 0.00886984239617046
INFO  Event ended: publish:statusUpdated. Elapsed: 0.0692825484803236
INFO  Event started: database:propertychanged
INFO  Executed: Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.RemoteEventMap.<SetupGlobalEventSubscribers>b__14(). Elapsed: 0.0154349225949108
INFO  Event ended: database:propertychanged. Elapsed: 0.0610412775925432
Event started: database:propertychanged
Executed: Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.RemoteEventMap.<SetupGlobalEventSubscribers>b__14(). Elapsed: 0.0096380964619805
INFO  Event ended: database:propertychanged. Elapsed: 0.057968261329303
WARN  [WFFM] Tracker.Current.CurrentPage  is not initialized
WARN  [WFFM] Tracker.Current  is not initialized
WARN  [WFFM] CurrentSession  is not initialized
WARN  [WFFM] CurrentContact  is not initialized
WARN  [WFFM] Cannot save form to Db, required attributes are: IsXdbTrackerEnabled:True
WARN  [WFFM] Could not get pipeline: processMessage (domain: )
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Could not get pipeline: processMessage (domain: )
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Forms.Core.Dependencies.DefaultImplActionExecutor.ExecuteSaving(ID formID, ControlResult[] fields, IActionDefinition[] actionDefinitions, Boolean simpleAdapt, ID sessionID)

WARN  [WFFM] Could not get pipeline: errorSave (domain: )
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Could not get pipeline: errorSave (domain: )
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Forms.Core.Dependencies.DefaultImplActionExecutor.ExecuteSaving(ID formID, ControlResult[] fields, IActionDefinition[] actionDefinitions, Boolean simpleAdapt, ID sessionID)
   at Sitecore.Form.Core.FormDataHandler.ExecuteSaveActions(ID formId, ControlResult[] fields, IActionDefinition[] actions, IActionExecutor actionExecutor)
   at Sitecore.Form.Core.FormDataHandler.ProcessData(ID formID, ControlResult[] fields, IActionDefinition[] actions, IActionExecutor actionExecutor)
```

Followed all the steps mentioned in the installation guide.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The log entry "Cannot save form to Db, required attributes are: IsXdbTrackerEnabled:True"  does seem like a good idea on how to solve the error...

Check your config and make sure that `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` is set to true. (use /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx to verify)

Also check your config files (especially Sitecore.Forms.config) to see whether you actually have the `processMessage` pipeline mentioned in the logs. The errors do seem to point to a misconfiguration..

Comment: Thanks for your response Gatogordo, verified that Xdb.Tracking.Enabled is set to true.

Comment: Added to the answer - check your config files on CD, verify that the pipelines mentioned in the logs are actually there. Maybe compare the files to a clean install (or your working server).

Comment: You are right...I did a compare for the pipelines mentioned in both CM and CD and found few differences in CD as few tags are not well formed, which happened as a part of commenting out few hooks and events for this module installation. Working as expected once they are corrected.